# Owl carousel 2 active prev/next navigation on item

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, carousel, owl-carousel-2

i'm using owl-carousel2 to set a playlist of sound (with loop:true and center:true), all is working fine, but i cant find doc about my problem :

i'm trying to add prev/next navigation on each item on click. I want user can click on item of his choice and so it slide center to this item. 
It works with mouse slide, but not on item click.

Is there a way to do this ?

there is my carousel init :

```
owl.owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            center: true,
            margin:3,
            dot: false,
            nav: false,
            items:5,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:2
                },
                768:{
                    items:4
                },
                1200:{
                    items:5
                },
                1500:{
                    items:4
                }
            }
      });
```

I tried this :

```
owl.on('click', '.item', function (property) {
          console.log(property);
          owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
      });
```

It works, but only for next item, i dont find how to know if it's a prev click

Thanks for help

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

It is same trigger for previous. See the example code:

```
$(".prev").on('click', function () {
    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess: **Your target is to click owl item and auto scroll left or right one item.**

*If yes, make sure your items length > 1.*

And try with below code:

```
owl.on('click', '.item', function (property) {
        var $currentItem = $(property.target).closest('.owl-item');
        var $activeItems = owl.find('.active');
        if ($currentItem.index() - $($activeItems[0]).index() <= $activeItems.length / 2 - 1)
        {
            owl.trigger('prev.owl');
        }
        else if ($($activeItems[$activeItems.length - 1]).index() - $currentItem.index() <= $activeItems.length / 2 - 1)
        {
            owl.trigger('next.owl');
        }
    });
```